# Poisson arrival conditional probability

Tags: conditional-probability, expected-value, poisson-distribution, poisson-process, gamma-distribution

> A meteorite shower is a poisson arrival with a rate of 16.6 per minute. Given that 7 meteorites were observed during the first minute, what is the expected value of the time passed until the 10'th meteorite is observed

Extracting info from the question gives us: $$N_t \sim Pois(16.6t)$$
$$T_{i+1}-T_i \sim Exp(16.6)$$
$$T_i \sim Gamma(i,16.6)$$

We want to find $E(T_{10}|N_1=7)$. These two variables are dependent so by definition:
$$E(T_{10}|N_1=7)=\int_{0}^{\infty} tP(T_{10} = t|N_1=7) dt$$
The only thing i could extract from that conditional probability is that the integral should start from 1, because the tenth arrival could not have been during the first minute. Also, i don't know any good way of opening up the following:
$$=\int_{1}^{\infty} t\dfrac{P(T_{10} = t,N_1=7)}{N_1=7)} dt$$

Is there an easier way to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is equivalent to asking how much time, on average, it will take to observe three more meteorites.  This is just the expectation of a gamma random variable with shape $n = 3$ and rate $\lambda = 16.6$; i.e., it will take on average $3/16.6 \approx 0.180723$ minutes, or about $10.8$ seconds.  This does not include the one minute that it took to observe $7$ meteorites.